# ajax queries still waiting after window close

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache

I have webpage that has an ajax call that gets data from a php script.

```
ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "submit.php?id=" + id, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

Inside the submit.php I wait for a binary to finish and create an outfile.

```
while(1){
    if(is_file($OUTFILEPATH)){
        break;
    }else{
        sleep(60);
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the user closes the browser window, the ajax call and corresponding httpd are not aborted.

And if the user refreshes the webpage multiple times, I end up having hundreds of httpd processes all waiting for the the same outfile to be created.

```
Apache Server Status
115 requests currently being processed, 5 idle workers

WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW_W____........
................................................................
................................................................

Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
```

Comment: sleep() is not interruptable, i.e. it isn't affected by the closed connection.

Comment: Since sleep() is uninterruptible, does a kill signal get sent but ignored by php, and then when the php script comes back, the kill signal is already past?   If this is the case (that a kill sig is sent but ignored), would an exec('sleep(60'))  be a work around?  That way if php receives a kill signal, it can kill the exec.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer was that I needed to send data to the client (which is closed), and that causes php to realize the connection has been closed, then you have to exit the script.

```
while(1){
    if(is_file($OUTFILEPATH)){
        break;
    }else{
        sleep(60);
        print " ";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if(connection_aborted() != 0{
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that this does not work on php 5.1 due to a bug with connection_aborted().  It works fine on php 5.3+